# haskell reading and iterating

Tags: loops, haskell

I need your help guys. 
Im trying to learn and do a simple task in haskell, but it's still hard for me.
What im trying to do is: Read a line of numbers separated with whitespace, iterate over that list, check values, and if values are not zero add 1 otherwise -1. I was trying to do it watching some tutorials and other project code, but it just outputs a bunch of errors.
My code:

```
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf
import Data.List
import System.IO

solve :: IO ()
solve = do
    nums <- map read . words <$> getLine
    print (calculate nums)

calculate (x:xs) = x + check xs

check num
    | num == 0 =
        -1
    | otherwise = 
        1

main :: IO ()
main = do
    n <- readLn
    if n /= 0
        then do 
            printf "Case: "
            solve
        else main
```

Errors:

```
C:\Users\Donatas\Documents\haskell\la3.hs:9:21: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `b0' arising from a use of `read'
      prevents the constraint `(Read b0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `b0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Read BufferMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
        instance Read Newline -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
        instance Read NewlineMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
        ...plus 25 others
        ...plus six instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In the first argument of `map', namely `read'
      In the first argument of `(.)', namely `map read'
      In the first argument of `(<$>)', namely `map read . words'
  |
9 |         nums <- map read . words <$> getLine
  |                     ^^^^

C:\Users\Donatas\Documents\haskell\la3.hs:10:9: error:
    * Ambiguous type variable `a0' arising from a use of `print'
      prevents the constraint `(Show a0)' from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what `a0' should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show HandlePosn -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle'
        instance Show BufferMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
        instance Show Handle -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
        ...plus 27 others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: print (calculate nums)
      In the expression:
        do nums <- map read . words <$> getLine
           print (calculate nums)
      In an equation for `solve':
          solve
            = do nums <- map read . words <$> getLine
                 print (calculate nums)
   |
10 |         print (calculate nums)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

C:\Users\Donatas\Documents\haskell\la3.hs:12:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        calculate :: forall a. (Eq a, Num [a], Num a) => [a] -> a
   |
12 | calculate (x:xs) = x + check xs
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Can you include the bunch of errors? Usually those are quite informative.

Comment: Included errors

Comment: `Ambiguous type variable 'b0' arising from a use of 'read'` Nowhere in your program does it say that you want to work with integers. The `read` function needs to know what it is supposed to read. You can probably fix that by adding type declarations for `check` and `calculate` (good practice anyway)

Comment: You have 2 IO monads, I would try to use 1 and do the rest in the functional part.

Answer (score 4):

To start with, I suggest you default to always writing type annotations. And before you start implementing anything, sketch out what the types of your program look like. For this program I suggest you start from:

```
main :: IO ()

solve :: String -> String

calculate :: [Int] -> Int

check :: Int -> Int
```

The names could also probably be improved to better convey what it is they're doing.

Note that there is only one function with type `IO _`. This serves to isolate the impure part of your program, which will make your life easier (e.g. testing, code reasoning, etc).

You're not far off. Just try reworking your code to fit into the above types. And be aware that you're missing a pattern in your `calculate` implementation  ;)

Comment: Perhaps a `getInts = map read . words <$> getLine` of type `IO [Int]` as an interface between `main` and `calculate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your code and follow the types, it is crystal-clear where the error is. Yes, you can add type annotations -- that is highly recommended -- but I find your code is so simple you could get away with just a bit of equational reasoning.

It starts with `solve`, it is easy to see that `nums` is of type `Read a => [a]`, given that you split a string by words (i.e. `[String]`) and map `read` over it. So a list of `a`s is what you give to `calculate`. As you know, a list is the disjoint sum between (1) the empty list (`[]`) and (2) a cons cell made of a head, an element of type `a`, and a tail, the rest of the list (`(x:xs)`).

First thing you notice is that the case of the empty list is missing; let's add it:

```
calculate [] = 0 -- I assume this is correct
```

On to the body of `calculate` and `check`. The latter clearly expects a number, you can be a bit more concise by the way:

```
check 0 = -1
check _ = 1
```

Now if you look at `calculate`, you see that you are calling `check` and passing it `xs`. What is `xs`? It is bound in the pattern `(x:xs)` which is how you uncons a cons cell. Clearly, `xs` is the tail of the cell and so a list itself. But `check` expects a number! The only number you can expect here is `x`, not `xs`. So let's change you code to

```
calculate (x:xs) = check x + ...
```

Your specifications state that you want to iterate over the list. That can only happen if you do something with `xs`. What can you do with it? The only answer to that is to call `calculate` recursively:

```
calculate (x:xs) = check x + calculate xs
```

... and with these changes, your code is fine.